# How to listen to Hong Kong RTHK Radio with Lubuntu?

Tags: plugins, streaming

I want to [listen to RTHK](http://programme.rthk.hk/channel/radio/player_popup.php?pid=3973&eid=250568&d=2014-02-07&player=mp3&type=archive&channel=radio2) with Lubuntu 13.10   Firefox 26.0.

However,  when I went to the above webpage(for example), 
Firefox always asks me to select a player for it.
I tried to select mplayer, vlc, Audacious, ...
but it doesn't work.

Is there a way to solve this problem? Please help.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Sounds like you don't have ubuntu-restricted-extras installed. I believe gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad is the actual package you are missing.

Comment: Thank you for the response!

I installed the " lubuntu-restricted-extras" with the following command:

sudo apt-get install lubuntu-restricted-extras

but it still doesn't work.

After the installation, I go to the link:
http://programme.rthk.hk/channel/radio/player_popup.php?pid=3973&eid=250568&d=2014-02-07&player=mp3&type=archive&channel=radio2

firefox asks me to select a player, I selected Audacious,
and the response is:

"No decoder found for file:///tmp/chunklist_w2083752485_b32000.m3u8."

Answer (score -1):

install Radiotray and configure the like http://stm.rthk.hk/radio1

Comment: Can you please expand your answer?